# Fire method on select change and pass selection

Tags: ember.js

How would I fire a method on a controller on a select change and pass the selection to the method? Something like this:

Template:

```
  {{view Em.Select content=users optionValuePath='content.id' optionLabelPath='content.firstName'}}
```

Controller:

```
assignUser: (user)->
  console.log user
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the selection to a controller property, then observe that property. For example:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  content=users
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
  selection=controller.selectedUser}}
```

Now update your controller:

```
App.RouteController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedUser: null,

  selectedUserDidChange: function () {
    if (this.get('selectedUser')) { // You might want more logic than this...
      this.assignUser();
    }
  }.observes('selectedUser'),

  assignUser: function () {
    console.log(this.get('selectedUser'));
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey again Matthew! Always coming to the rescue. So I see the answer above and it is using value= instead of selection=. Is there a difference?

Comment: Haha happy to help! Give it a try and you'll see. It has to do with how ember parses the option markup to provide you values. `value` will grab the actual value from the html tag. `selection` will give you the whole object that is represented in the option. I prefer the latter, but if you want a simple value, use that.

Comment: Great to know. So on your answer I'm slightly confused. If I wanted to run the assignUser when the selectedUser changes, would I add the observes to assignUser?

Comment: Nope I can add that in. You fire that from within the observer. Will update my answer.

Comment: Ahhh perfect. So convention is to have a ..DidChange property and then run the other methods within that?

Comment: @sturoid I should say in your case, `selection` is easier. You have the user object right there bound to the controller so you can treat `selectedUser` as a legit proxy. No need to look it up.

Comment: Exactly. It is just what they do in their own code. You don't have to do it, but it's easier for other ember devs to understand if you follow that. If you observe a `thing`, just call your observer method `thingDidChange`

Comment: Awesome. Sorry, what do you mean exactly by treating it as a legit proxy that I don't need to look up?

Comment: Sorry that didn't make any sense to me when I re-read it. What I meant is that you can call user methods from that controller property. If you just had the value, you'd have to use something like `any` to filter down your users collection each time a change is observed.

Comment: Hmmm I'm a noob and still don't understand but on a happy note I got the method working :)!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a `value` attribute to the view for the current selection:

```
{{view Em.Select content=users value=selectedUser optionValuePath='content.id' optionLabelPath='content.firstName'}}
```

Then, in your controller, you can access `selectedUser`:

```
doSomethingOnSelect: function() {
    var selected= this.get('selectedUser');
    // go do something with selected
}.observes('selectedUser')
```

Comment: I am amused that we both used nearly the same naming conventions. :) Just a heads up, Ember convention calls for `DidChange` as the suffix on observer methods. That said, convention is totally your call. Just noting it for potential Ember devs passing by.